# angular dynamic templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, angular-template

Hi have one more question, I have next config for angular:

```
angular.module('ow', []).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
    when('/:placeId', {templateUrl: 'partials/menu.html',   controller: MenuCtrl}).
    when('/menu/:itemId', {templateUrl: 'partials/menu-details.html', controller: MenuItemCtrl}).
    when('/look/refill', {templateUrl: 'partials/refill.html', controller: RefillCtrl}).
    when('/look/orderCart', {templateUrl: 'partials/orderCart.html', controller: OrderCartCtrl}).
    when('/lang/:lang', {templateUrl: 'partials/menu.html', controller: LangCtrl}).
    when('/waiter/:redirect', {templateUrl: "???????", controller: WaiterCtrl}).
    otherwise({redirectTo: '/0'});
}];
```

Instead of "?????" I need to put dynamic url, tried to do it in controller like:

```
function WaiterCtrl($routeParams, $location, sharedData, $http, $route) {
$http.get(config.urls.ajaxWaiter + "{\"p\":\"" + sharedData.getOrderCart().orderPlace + "\"}").success(function(dataDetails) {
    if ($routeParams.redirect == "menu") {
        $route.templateUrl = "partials/menu.html";
        $location.path("/");
    }
    if ($routeParams.redirect == "menuDetails") {
        $route.templateUrl = "partials/menu-details.html";
        $location.path("/menu/" + sharedData.getMenu());
    }
    if ($routeParams.redirect == "orderCart") {
        $route.templateUrl = "partials/orderCart.html";
        $location.path("/orderCart");
    }
    if ($routeParams.redirect == "refill") {
        $route.templateUrl = "partials/refill.html";
        $location.path("/refill");
    }
    return $route.templateUrl;
});
```

}

but it doesn't work... Can you help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You won't be able to put dynamic code into the routing. This is because the routing happens during the Config phase, which is executed before Angular starts running your application.

I think the easiest or cleanest way to do what you are trying to do is just have an inline controller in the route definition. I set up a simple plunk to show redirecting inside the route definition: http://plnkr.co/edit/aeSjmn?p=preview

Here's some sample code that might work for you:

```
angular.module('ow', []).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
    when('/:placeId', {templateUrl: 'partials/menu.html',   controller: MenuCtrl}).
    when('/menu/:itemId', {templateUrl: 'partials/menu-details.html', controller: MenuItemCtrl}).
    when('/look/refill', {templateUrl: 'partials/refill.html', controller: RefillCtrl}).
    when('/look/orderCart', {templateUrl: 'partials/orderCart.html', controller: OrderCartCtrl}).
    when('/lang/:lang', {templateUrl: 'partials/menu.html', controller: LangCtrl}).
    when('/waiter/:redirect', {template: '', controller: function ($scope, $routeParams, $location) {
      function WaiterCtrl($routeParams, $location, sharedData, $http, $route) {
        $http.get(config.urls.ajaxWaiter + "{\"p\":\"" + sharedData.getOrderCart().orderPlace + "\"}").success(function(dataDetails) {
            if ($routeParams.redirect == "menu") 
              $location.path("/");
            else
              $location.path("/" + $routeParams.redirect);
        })
    }}).
    otherwise({redirectTo: '/0'});
}];
```