# Link param in config

Tags: angularjs

I started a new project like the phoneCat app tutorial and want to modify it.
On my main page I have a link for my examples (partial pages):

```
<a href="/examples/{{item.id}}" ><h4>{{item.name}}</h4></a>
```

In my app.js, I made a route :

```
.when('/examples/:id', {templateUrl: '/questions/examples/???', controller: ExampleCtrl})
```

How I can load a page like "/questions/examples/2menu.html" in my 'ng-view' through my routing? 
In other words, how I can paste `{{item.id}}` from main page to '???'? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [angular dynamic templateUrl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16316087/angular-dynamic-templateurl)

Answer (score 0):

Try using ng-include for this. The idea is that you will get the id from the route parameter, use it to create a URL to your specific example template, then use the ng-include directive to load that template.

```
.when('/examples/:id', {
    templateUrl: '/questions/examples.html', controller: ExampleCtrl})
```

In ExampleCtrl:

```
function PhoneDetailCtrl($scope, $routeParams, Phone) {
    $scope.theIncludeUrl = "/questions/examples/" + $routeParams.id + "menu.html";
});
```

In examples.html:

```
<div ng-include="theIncludeUrl"></div>
```